# Show pop up to users who downvote spam question to flag it as spam

Tags: discussion

I lost track of the count of spam posts that came in today morning. One thing which I noticed was that as usual there were 8 or 9 downvotes to all of these questions instead if they were flagged they would have been deleted.

Many users dont know that they can mark it as spam which will trigger auto deletion of post. Similar to the popup which tells user s to leave a comment when question is downvoted, can we disaplay another pop up which suggests the user to mark the question as flag if and only if the question is already marked as spam by X no of users.

Comment: I agree to this 100%. A user is encouraged to leave a comment when s/he down-votes on a post. That pop-up could have a line to let the users know about the use of flagging it as a spam :-)

Comment: I made a very similar feature requests on Meta.SO a while ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148691/151385

Comment: I like this idea a lot. If this doesn't get any traction I'll try putting a bounty on the Meta.SO question and get it some attention

Comment: @clive having flagged spam before here. i for one think its confusing to be allocated like 20 or so flag allotments that make it seem as a new user you can only flag X numbers of things before you cant anymore ... i understand now the throttling. i'm just saying i think that's confusing for new users as well. Hence they downvote.

Comment: @tenken I don't personally have a problem with downvoting spam posts, I do it myself. But I agree, if that was changed to add _per day_ then things would be a bit clearer for new users